# Problemas para convertir a Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode

nose si vosotrois estais teniendo tambien problemas para convertir a Swift 3 sobre todo con los frameworks como Alamofire y demas , me saltan miles de errores imposibles de solucionar , no se como estais enfrentando estos problemas ?

Comment: Un dolor de cabeza!, en cuanto a Alamofire ya tienen un documento especifico para migración a Swift 3 https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1316 esta en inglés, si necesitas traducción te ayudamos.

Comment: Hey gracias , la verdad que Alamofire en este caso actualizando a la última versión ya lo soluciona , el problema son las librerías que no han sacado actualización que ya me diras tu si hemos de ir modificandolas ... pero bueno espero que todas se actualizen pronto! Gracias

Comment: A mi tyambien me ha pasado lo mismo, pero muchas librerias ya se han actualizado a swift 3. Como es el caso de alamofire, snapkit, ... Lo puedes ver en sus github

Comment: A mí me paso el primer día de actualización. Evidentemente no había soporte de todas las librerías todavía a Swift 3 por lo que tuve que rehacer el proyecto de nuevo. Sí, fue a la desesperada ya que me estuve como tres días intentando solucionarlo sin obtener una solución.

Comment: No es necesario migrar Alamofire, simplemente cambiar el pod para que ponga una versión en Swift 3, como dice @ChristianGonzalez

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

1) Elimine mi archivo pod.

2) Me he creado un nuevo archivo pod utilizando Pod init desde el terminal

3) Use esta estructura:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MiApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for YoVendoSaldo
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'SVProgressHUD'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'

end
```